# make table rows and following cells as mandatory fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>id</tr>
      <input type="text" id= "101"  style = "color:black" required></td>
      <input type="button"  value="Submit"  style = "color:Red;">
<script>
document.getElementById("101").reset()
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```

1) i want to make mandatory my id field but i am unable to do it .I used required but it is  not working

2) i want to empty my text fields after submitting the fields when user clicks submit it is not working

3)In my code i used tr as text fields plese suggest for following tr tag only

Comment: `type="button"` this is a button, if you need submit as button use `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

First, your html markup is wrong (inside TR you need to put TD), plus you are missing the form tag.

Adding the form tag, the page will submit and refresh. Te text field will be blank by default, no need to use javascript.

"required" is a HTML5 tag, it will work only with html5 browser that support it.
This code will work with every compatible html5 browser

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>id</td>
          <td><input type="text" id= "101"  style = "color:black" required></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  value="Submit"  style = "color:Red;"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you are missign a semi-colon in your input field. Should be

   `<input type="text"  id="101"  style="color:black;" required>`

   *In general it's preferable to create a separate `.css` file rather than utilizing the style attirbute*

---

2. In general you are invokingthe javascript incorrectly.

   `<input type="button"  value="Submit"  style = "color:Red;" onclick="clearInput()">`

---

2. And you should change the javascript  accordingly:

   ```
   <script>
    function clearInput() {
      document.GetElementById('101').value = "";
    }
   </script>
   ```

---

3. Your table form in general is wrong. Your general structure should look something like this

   `<table>
         <td>
            <tr>1</tr>
            <tr>2</tr>
         </td>
         <td>
            <tr>Column 2 Row</tr>
         </td>
     </table>`

A working js fiddle example:

```js
function clearInput() {
  document.getElementById('101').value = "";
}
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="101">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="clearInput()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your code inside `<form>` and just submit type is enough to reset it. No need to write javascript to reset. Here is your working code snippet:

```
  <body>
    <form>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id= "101"  style = "color:black" required></td>
            <td><input type="submit"  value="Submit"  style = "color:Red;"></td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </body>
```

If you want separate reset button to reset the field, add this in your table:

```
<td><input type="reset"  value="Reset"  style = "color:Red;"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an "editable grid" i.e. a table like structure that allows you to make any of the rows a form, use CSS that mimics the TABLE tag's layout: display:table, display:table-row, and display:table-cell.

There is no need to wrap your whole table in a form and no need to create a separate form and table for each apparent row of your table.

Try this instead:

```
<style>
  DIV.table 
  {
      display:table;
  }
  FORM.tr, DIV.tr
  {
      display:table-row;
  }
  SPAN.td
  {
      display:table-cell;
  }
</style>

<div class="table">
  <form class="tr" method="post" action="blah.html">
    <span class="td"><input type="text"/></span>
    <span class="td"><input type="text"/></span>
  </form>
  <div class="tr">
    <span class="td">(cell data)</span>
    <span class="td">(cell data)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with wrapping the whole TABLE in a FORM is that any and all form elements will be sent on submit (maybe that is desired but probably not). This method allows you to define a form for each "row" and send only that row of data on submit.

The problem with wrapping a FORM tag around a TR tag (or TR around a FORM) is that its invalid HTML. The FORM will still allow submitting as usual but at this point, the DOM is broken. Note: Try getting the child elements of your FORM or TR with JavaScript, it can lead to unexpected results.

Note that IE7 doesn't support these CSS table styles and IE8 will need a doctype declaration to get it into "standards" mode: (try this one or something equivalent)

Any other browser that supports display:table, display:table-row and display:table-cell should display your CSS data table the same as it would if you were using the TABLE, TR and TD tags. Most of them do.

Note that you can also mimic THEAD, TBODY, TFOOT by wrapping your row groups in another DIV with display: table-header-group, table-row-group, and table-footer-group respectively